# Regex for comma separated time in HH:mm or HH:mm:ss in Java e.g. 12:00,13:03:21

Tags: java, regex, spring

I need regex which can match Comma separated time like 12:00,13:03:21,12:50 there can be any number of comma separated times. I am splitting this with , in code I am using match function to check this regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex would do the trick :

```
^(?:[01]\d|2[1-3]):[0-5]\d(?::[0-5]\d)?(?:,(?:[01]\d|2[1-3]):[0-5]\d(?::[0-5]\d)?)*$
```

You can [try it here](https://regex101.com/r/VPmovd/2).

Note that if your code is doing anything more with that input than validating it (i.e. if you're going to use the times as such, do any kind of time arithmetics) then it would make more sense to simply split the string over `,` and then use `LocalTime.parse(CharSequence text)` to validate the parts while mapping them into a more useful datatype.